# Hard negative mining to a specific object in image for SSD training

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I use [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) for my object detection. 
I used SSD with caffe. SSD is Convolutional Neural Network for multiple object size detection.
The sensitivity of detection is quite good.
But specificity has issue with detecting same objects consistently. What would be the right approach to reject those objects in detection.
I know SSD has hard negative mining and I am trying to include those objects in hard negative mining.
Would this approach correct or are there any better ways to reject those using SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for hard negative mining for SSD is that I create an image with all those objects giving false positive in different sizes. I made a few such images in training. Then according to 1:3 ratio, these objects will be taken for hard negative mining.